# Planning to retake English language test for PhD admissions in the UK, but listed previous average in my CV - should I contact professor to explain?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-kingdom, language-exams

I participated to an English language test in the autumn. My average score was very good, and above the requirement of a program I am applying to. However, the score of one of the sub-components was less than the given requirement (surprisingly low, but I have no idea why). I had indicated my average score in my CV, but I did not send the test results with the application, because I will soon resit the test. It was not possible to write an explanation on the application form.

Should I contact the professor and explain the situation? He might be wondering why my CV says something and the application something else. Or is this usual, that the document arrives later than the rest of the application (which is allowed according to the application guidelines)?

I would not like to appear as marketing a passing score but not actually having one instead. So, is it better than (1) I bother them, or (2) let them ask if it matters?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely contact the professor. English is just a trivial component in your application, so you should not worry about it. Especially, you will likely have an interview if you are shortlisted.

When I applied to Oxford, my IELTS score was only 6.5, while the school required 7 (and no band is less than 6). I contacted the professor, and she told her assistant (who collected the applications) that it was OK for that position with 6.5.

I was later rejected, but it was due to my lack of research experience, not my English score.